# What is a Application/Service Certificate compliant with FIPS 140-2

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, amazon-web-services

I have enabled FIPS on my AWS EC2s and updated the prefix's as shown here: https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/fips/

All of this is working in the AMI Build & Pipeline, however, at the application level we are getting a certificate error. Any ideas on if a new certificate needs to be issued and which certificate would be best?

Here is the specific error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDeffFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.ssl.SignatureScheme
```

Comment: What version of Java do you have exactly?  There is a known bug in Java 8 331 and that causes a NoClassDeffFoundError

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65644914/2908599) seems like you have standart Java. And this class `sun.security.ssl.SignatureScheme` is part of OpenJDK. Install it and try again. Here is official web site for reference: https://adoptopenjdk.net/